# Pandas df showing up as 'NaN' once I write data to an excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

To give a quick background, I am downloading a table online and writing it into 'tab2' of an excel sheet. 'Tab1' then acts as a summary tab which compares the current table to the previous version I last downloaded.

Now, to tell the difference between the two tables, I've set up an IF function which shows "True" if there's no movement, and "False" if there's a movement.

I've then used Pandas to filter the dataframe for any instances in the "Overall" column which are "True".

However, this only works if I use it in isolation without the automated file download. As soon as I run the whole script including the download + write, it shows the "True/False" column as "NaN" - Which means it then filters out all the lines.

The filter code is as follows:

```
# Open File
file_read = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Summary')
print(file_read)
    
# Filter by 'Overall' = TRUE
Movement = file_read[(file_read['Overall'] == True )]
print(Movement)
    
Movement.to_excel('Output.xlsx')
```

The Download + Writer code is as follows:

```
book = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, 'TAB NAME', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the column affected. What does it look like to openpyxl?

Comment: Apologies, what do you mean by 'What does it look like to OpenPyxl'?

Anything which is formula based within the dataframe is turned into "NaN" once OpenPyxl is utilised, no matter what the formula is.

Comment: Well, formulae like `SUM(A1:A6)` aren't numbers which is why Pandas converts them to `NaN`. I suggest you read the openpyxl documentation regarding formulae.

Comment: This is likely the problem. Looking at it purely from a 'data frame only' perspective it seems to be fine. But when bringing the openpyxl aspect into it, that's where the problem arises. So, I'm guessing when creating a data frame immediately after the openpyxl action, it causes the df to still be in 'openpyxl mode'. I'll look into your suggestion - any specific area of documentation you recommend?

Comment: I think I need to try: openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = xxxx,data_only=True)

Will give it a go in the office tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following line in your second to last line:

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TAB NAME', index=False, na_rep='')
```

na_rep will define what will be displayed in emtpy cells.

Take care, friend

Comment: Didn't work.

To be clear, the cells aren't actually empty - They have either "True" or "False" in them based on a formula. But it seems something in the writing/openpyxl process is causing the NaN to appear in Pandas.

If I manually open the file, and save it. Then run JUST the dataframe print - I can see it as "True" and "False" rather than NaN.